# Is it possible to have users not pip install modules and instead include the modules used in a different folder and then import that?

Tags: python

I want to know if I can create a python script with a folder in the same directory with all the assets of a python module, so when someone wants to use it, they would not have to pip install module, because it would import from the directory.

Comment: You can use pip to install in a different directory , pip install --target=<YOUR PATH> <Module Name>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it doesn't mean that you should.

First, ask yourself who is suposed to use that code.

If you plan to give it to consumers, it would be a good idea to use a tool like py2exe and create executable file which would include all modules and not allow for code to be changed.

If you plan to share it with another developer, you might want to look into virtual environments and requirements.txt file.

There are multiple reasons why sharing modules is bad idea:

1. It is harder to update modules later, at least without upgrading whole project.
2. It uses more space on version control, which can create issues on huge projects with hundreds of modules and branches
3. It might be illegal as some licenses specifically forbid including their code in your source code.
4. The `pip install` of some module might do different things depending on operating system version or installed packages. The modules on your machine might be suboptimal on someone else's machine, and in some instances might not even work.

And probably more that I can't think of right now.

The only situation where I saw this being unavoidable was when the module didn't support python implementation the application was running on. The module was changed, and its source was put under lib folder with the rest of the libraries.

Comment: Now that I've converted to exe, how would I change the icon of the file? I don't particularly like the default one for the exe conversion.

Comment: You need to add **icon_resources** option.
`setup(console=[{
    'script': 'simple_text.py',
    'icon_resources': [(0, 'favicon.ico')]
}])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the directory with python modules into `PYTHONPATH`. Then people want to use those modules just need has this envvar set.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH